# VSCode with WSL Remote + Golang gopls installation is failing with the error

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When VSCode is trying to install the golang.org/x/tools/gopls, it is throwing the below error.

```
get "golang.org/x/tools": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191108194844-46f05828f2fe
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.2.0
golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/source
# golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/source
../../../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/source/completion.go:697:21: file.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
../../../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/source/format.go:246:27: fset.File(f.Pos()).LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
../../../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/source/format.go:271:13: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue trying to build my completion for VIM w/ YouCompleteMe:

```
# golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/source
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/source/completion.go:697:21: file.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/source/format.go:246:27: fset.File(f.Pos()).LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
third_party/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.0.0-20200407041343-bf15fae40dea/internal/lsp/source/format.go:271:13: tok.LineStart undefined (type *token.File has no field or method LineStart)
```

**Solution:**

Switching from go 1.11.4 to 1.12beta1 seems to have fixed this issue for me!

Comment: 1. Do not run this command where go.mod exits
2. Try to delete the old version from here `rm -r $GOPATH/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools/gopls@VERSIONHERE/` and retry if you are not running from go.mod location.